# Align div with right edge of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a button (div with background color) just below an image that aligns with right side of the image.  Both are inside a wrapper div.  When I float right the button it makes the wrapper div expand and the button goes beyond the right edge of the img.  I cannot give the wrapper div a fixed width as it needs to be responsive.

What I have:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">

   <div class="wrapper">

      <h2>Title</h2>

      <img class="responsive">

      <div class="button"></div>

   </div>

</div>


.button {
  float: right;
 }
```

Basically, how do I make the wrapper div match the width of the image?  Or some other way to get the button div align with the right edge of the image.

The Image is about 70% width of the col-xs-6 div, and I can't make it take up the whole div, there is another image next to it and there needs to be a good space between.

Note: I'm using bootstrap for the responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper{text-align:right;}
.responsive{width:100%; height:auto}
```

and then if you need the h2 to be aligned differently, you can align it like `h2{text-align:center}`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the image needs to be aligned to the left side of the page. When I tried text-align:right it moved the image as well as the button all the way to the right side of the wrapper, and the whole wrapper dive stretches over to the right side of div.col-xs-6.  Also cannot make the image wider then it is.

Comment: then give a class to col-xs-6 (just in case) and give it `text-align:left;` after that, add a max-width to the wrapper which equals the current width of your image and that's it

Comment: For some reason the button div would not align to the right after adding text-align:left to the col-xs-6.  But was able to add float: right; to the button. Voila!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using boostrap I'd do it like this (if that's what you mean):

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="some text" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">some text</button>
</div>
```

EDIT: sorry, corrected the button element